# Get _id's of the updated documents in MongoDB - Python

Tags: python, mongodb

I am bulk-updating data to a MongoDB database in python using pymongo with the following code:

```
# Update data
if data_to_be_updated:
  update = collection.bulk_write([
    UpdateOne(
      filter = {'source_id': item['source_id']},
        update = {'$set': item}
      ) for item in data_to_be_updated
    ])
```

How do I get the `MongoDB` _id's of the updated documents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `update` variable should have an attribute `bulk_api_result` containing information about what was changed in the bulk operation.

`update.bulk_api_result['upserted']` will contain a list of the documents that were updated