# Upsert with Pymongo - How to get _id of updated document?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm using Pymongo to read and write to a MongoDB collection. Per the documentation, the update and update_one functions return an UpdateResult object:
https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/results.html#pymongo.results.UpdateResult

If you use `upsert=true` and an insert takes place, the `UpdateResult` object includes an "upserted_id" field containing the `_id` of the document that was just inserted. I'd also like to know what the `_id` was if I update an existing document. However, as far as I can tell from the documentation and testing it in Python, no `_id` is returned if an existing document is updated.
Am I missing something? Why wouldn't `UpdateResult` want to return an `_id` regardless of if it was an updated document or an inserted one? What is the intended way for me to find out what documents were updated when performing database operations?

Using Python version 3.10.8.

- Checked the documentation to see the return type of Pymongo update_one.
- Ran the following query locally:

```
client = MongoClient(connection_uri)
database = client["example_db"]
collection = database["sample_collection"]

# insert new existing record
result = collection.update_one(filter_query, update_operation, upsert=True)
print(result.upserted_id) # *******************

# update an existing record
result = collection.update_one(filter_query, update_operation, upsert=True)
print(result.upserted_id) # None

print(result.raw_result) # {'n': 1, 'nModified': 1, 'ok': 1.0, 'updatedExisting': True}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only concerned with updating one document, you can replace `update` with `find_one_and_update`:

```
result = collection.find_one_and_update(
            filter=filter_query,
            update=update_operation,
            upsert=True,
            return_document=True,
        )
        
print(result["_id"])
```

The above code will return the entire document that was updated/inserted. Additionally, if you only care about the `_id` and nothing else, you can include the optional argument `projection={"_id": True}`.

The case of updating multiple records is covered in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45867153/11086614